# xamarin mvvm update from different class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I read several similar issues with MVVM, but just cannot find the right fix to this problem. I am sure it's really simple, but I cannot work out how to update an UI from two different classes.

I have one ModelView (Homepage.xaml) and MVVM binded label, which works fine from the Homepage.cs, but how can I update this label from from a different class (anotheractivty.cs). Is there a way to reference the string from from the second class file or do I need to somehow call and pass the string between the anotheractivty to the homepage class?

Many thanks

Please note the code is simplified:

Homepage.xaml

```
  <Label
  Text={"Binding Updatetext}"
  />
```

Homepage.xaml.cs

```
String updatetext = "";

public Homepage()
{
   BindingContent = this;
}

Public string Updatetext
{
     get=> updatetext
     set 
     {
          if (value == updatetext)
             return;

          updatetext = value;
          OnPropertyChange(nameof(Updatetext));
     }
}

Public updatetest()
{ 
   
   Updatetext = "new text";

}
```

anotheractivty.cs

How to link this to the Homepage.cs?

```
Public updatetest()
{
   var page = new Homepage;
   Homepage.Updatetext = "new text";

}
```

Comment: Xamarin is a C# framework. Why is this tagged "java"?

Comment: Good point, not sure how it was tagged with Java updated for c#

Comment: You can use messageCenter to achieve it, send the value from `anotheractivty.cs` to the `Homepage`, then set it to  `Updatetext` directly.